# How to delete the current leaflet marker when create new search?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have created this component for dispay a marker when i search a city, but when i create a new search a new marker as added but the previous as not deleted. Have you an idea for resolve this problem ?

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js";
import L from "leaflet";
import icon from "./../constants/homeIcon";

import { PrintAddress } from "../components/Map/styles";

const SearchBar = () => {
  const map = useMap();

  let [printInfo, setPrintinfo] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    let geocoder = L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim({
      geocodingQueryParams: {
        limit: 3,
        addressdetails: 1,
        namedetails: 1,
        countrycodes: "fr",
      },
    });
    L.Control.geocoder({
      query: "",
      placeholder: "Search your address",
      defaultMarkGeocode: false,
      geocoder,
    })
      .on("markgeocode", function (e) {
        let latlng = e.geocode.center;
        L.marker(latlng, { icon })
          .bindPopup(e.geocode.name)
          .openPopup()
          .addTo(map);
        map.panTo(latlng);
        L.circle(latlng, {
          color: "#000",
          fillColor: "#7AEDAD",
          radius: 10000,
        }).addTo(map);
        setPrintinfo(e.geocode.name);
      })
      .addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return <PrintAddress className="printInfo">{printInfo}</PrintAddress>;
};
export default SearchBar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a layerGroup outside the component to store the circle and the marker and every time you add a new marker clear the layer Group and add the new to be able to delete it the next time you add another marker.

```
 const layerGroup = L.layerGroup(); // init the empty layerGroup
    
    const SearchBar = () => {
      const map = useMap(); 
      ...
 L.Control.geocoder({
      query: '',
      placeholder: 'Search your address',
      defaultMarkGeocode: false,
      geocoder
    })
      .on('markgeocode', function (e) {
        layerGroup.clearLayers();  // lear the layerGroup from previous stored circle and marker
        let latlng = e.geocode.center;
        L.marker(latlng, { icon })
          .bindPopup(e.geocode.name)
          .openPopup()
          .addTo(layerGroup); // add the marker to the layerGroup

        map.panTo(latlng);

        L.circle(latlng, {
          color: '#000',
          fillColor: '#7AEDAD',
          radius: 10000
        }).addTo(layerGroup); // add the circle to th elayerGroup

        setPrintinfo(e.geocode.name);

        map.addLayer(layerGroup);  // here add the layerGroup to th emap
      })
      .addTo(map);
  }, [map]);
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-delete-the-current-leaflet-marker-when-create-new-search-in-react-leaflet-v3x-gdxs3?file=/src/SearchBar.jsx)

Comment: Great !  Thank you for your help !